# is it possiable to send the message or notification to all android device on the same local area

Tags: android, push-notification

is it possiable to send the message or notification when on the same local network,to all android phone without using additional programme or codeing on the android device.I know push messaging but ,on this method,I need to install additionall software on android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not.

Not without installing your app on all the devices.